# How can I call the .username property in my embed ? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, referenceerror

Hello everyone :) The title is a bit weird I guess but I am new to this and I'm trying to figure it out with my own words.

Basically what I have done is a "embeds-orders.js" file which will regroup a few embeds so I can call theses embeds in my main.js file without taking space in it.

**My issue :** I would like to write in the embed's description the username of who triggered it. I would've used "user.username" or something but I get a ReferenceError since I didn't define user.
So I guess that I need to import something such as a class to my file in order to that ? I'm ready to learn from you guys :D

*↓ Here is my **"embeds-orders.js"** file   ↓*

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

        const orderStarter = new MessageEmbed()

    .setAuthor("STARTER RECOVERY ", "https://i.imgur.com/YOZP0xO.png")
        .setDescription(
            "Hello " + user.username + ", welcome." 
        )           /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
        .setColor("3232FF")
        .setThumbnail(
            "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/224553787824668673/716765453548126228/icon.png.fe88fd1ca437c86cde7cd99961673ef8.png"
        )
        .addFields(
            {
                name: "__Wanna Cancel ?__ ",
                value: "Type `!cancel`",
                inline: true,
            }
        )
        
        module.exports =  {
            orderStarter
        }
```

Comment: `message.author.username`

Comment: @Lioness100 nope message won't work I kinda need to import the class or object I need to use it

Comment: How is the user triggering it

Comment: @Lioness100 oh yeah I forgot about that. User triggers it by reacting to an emoji, my messageReactionAdd Event is in my main.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to dynamically specify who triggered the embed, you should make it a function.

```js
module.exports = (username) => {
 const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

 return new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor('STARTER RECOVERY ', 'https://i.imgur.com/YOZP0xO.png')
  .setDescription(`Hello ${username}, welcome.')
  .setColor('3232FF')
  .setThumbnail('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/224553787824668673/716765453548126228/icon.png.fe88fd1ca437c86cde7cd99961673ef8.png')
  .addField('__Wanna Cancel ?__ ', 'Type `!cancel`', true);
};
```

Then, when you need to send the embed, just pass the username as a parameter. For example, if this is taking place in a `message` event:

```js
const embed = require('./embeds-orders.js');

client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content === 'I want to order the embed')
  message.channel.send(embed(message.author.username));
});
```

Edit: in a `messageReactionAdd` event:

```js
const embed = require('./embeds-orders.js');

client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  // bla bla bla
  message.channel.send(embed(user.username));
```

Edit #2: You can just edit the function to add more parameters.

```js
module.exports = (author, description, color) => {
 const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

 return new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(...author) // author can be an array with the text and the url as elements
  .setDescription(description)
  .setColor(color)
  .setThumbnail(
   'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/224553787824668673/716765453548126228/icon.png.fe88fd1ca437c86cde7cd99961673ef8.png'
  )
  .addField('__Wanna Cancel ?__ ', 'Type `!cancel`', true);
};
```

```js
const embed = require('./embeds-orders.js');

client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  // bla bla bla
 reaction.emoji.name === "Emoji Name"
  ? message.channel.send(embed(["author text", "url"], "description", "color"))
  : message.channel.send(
      embed(
        ["different author text", "url"],
        "different description",
        "different color"
      )
    );
```